# mysql_num_rows error in PHP with mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-num-rows

Hi i am too new too php and mysql and  i want to count the member number due to the search made by user. However, `mysql_num_rows` doesnt work.

```
mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE $title LIKE '%$_POST[search]%' LIMIT $start,$member_number"));
```

It says **"mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in ..."**

*NOTE:* $title is a select menu which user choose where to search. LIMIT is, as you know :), number of member which is shown in a page.

And also `$start= ($page-1)*$member_number;`    in order to set the first entry in that page. I think the problem is here but i cant solve it.  :(

Comment: print out your query, maybe there's an error in there.

Comment: write vertically, not horizontally, dude. It will save you lot of trouble

Comment: what is "member number"?

Comment: number of member in db in members table.

Comment: why do you add it to LIMIT then?

Comment: for example i have 100 members and in the first page, the 5 members will be shown and in he second page it will start with 6 and the 5 members will be shown there and it will continue like that

Comment: well it is my first question and there can be nonsense and no-explanation in first questions.

Comment: @echophp: Please use the edit link (under the tags) to add clarifying details to your question.  It makes them more visible, since not everyone will read a comment thread.  Thanks, and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. If you need number of rows returned, you should use no LIMIT. if you're using LIMIT, it makes no sense to get ONLY number of rows returned and nothing else.

Answer (score 4):

Your query probably has an error, in which case mysql_query will return `false`.

For this reason, you should not group commands like this. Do it like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("...");

if (!$result)
 { echo mysql_error(); die(); } // or some other error handling method
                                // like, a generic error message on a public site

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Also, you have a number of [SQL injection vulnerabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection) in your code.  You need to sanitize the incoming `$search` variable:

```
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["search"]);

... mysql_query(".... WHERE $title LIKE '%$search%'");
```

if `$start` and `$end` come from outside, you also need to sanitize those before using them in your `LIMIT` clause. You can't use `mysql_real_escape_string()` here, because they are numeric values. Use `intval()` to make sure they contain only numbers.

Using a dynamic column name is also difficult from a sanitation point of view: You won't be able to apply `mysql_real_escape_string()` here, either. You should ideally compare against a list of allowed column names to prevent injection.

Comment: please avoid mysql_real_escape_string() .use mysql prepared statements.

Comment: you can miss escaping a variable.But if you follow prepared statements you are assure that it won't happen.Good Design..

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732561/why-is-using-a-mysql-prepared-statement-more-secure-than-using-the-common-escape

Comment: @Shashwhat while there are many advantages to PDO or mysqli, there is nothing essentially wrong with the mysql_ family of functions. Also, note that prepared statements will *not* help with a dynamic table name.

Comment: I agree with you.dynamic table names can't be use with prepared statements

Answer (score 2):

you have to use GET method in your form, not POST.

mysql_num_rows doesn't make sense here.
If you're using limit, you already know the number`*`.
If you want to know number, you shouldn't use limit nor request rows but select number itself.

```
// get your $title safe
$fields = array("name","lastname");
$key = array_search($_GET['title'],$fields));
$title = $fields[$key];

//escape your $search
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search']);

$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM members WHERE $title LIKE '%$search%'";
$res = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$sql); 
$row = mysql_fetch_row($res);

$members_found = $row[0]
```

in case you need just 5 records to show on the page, no need for mysql_num_rows() again:

```
// Get LIMIT params
$member_number = 5;
$start = 0;
if (isset($_GET['page'])){
  $start = abs($_GET['page']-1)*$member_number;
}
// get your $title safe
$fields = array("name","lastname");
$key = array_search($_GET['title'],$fields));
$title = $fields[$key];

//escape your $search
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search']);

$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM members 
          WHERE `$title` LIKE '%$search%' 
          LIMIT $start, $member_number";
$res = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res){
  $data[] = $row;
}
```

Now you have selected rows in $data for the further use.

Comment: This seems correct (and safe!) to me. Anyone care to explain the downvotes?

Comment: they can't downvote comments, but they don't like the truth. so, only answer votes they have :)

Comment: no, it's probably because you've become a bit of a target. see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85797/can-i-dispute-a-downvote

Comment: @Arjan thank you for your support, man. I know I did behave not so smart in this situation, but you was only one who judged fairly and who supported me on meta. I heartily thank you.

Comment: And only now I see that you got rid of the horizontal scrollbars! :-) Well, peace, please!

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error generally indicates there is an error in your SQL query -- so it has not been successful, and `mysql_query()` doesn't return a valid resource ; which, so, cannot be used as a parameter to `mysql_num_rows()`.

You should echo your SQL query, in order to check if it's build OK.

And/or, if `mysql_query()` returns `false`, you could use [**`mysql_error()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) to get the error message : it'll help you debug your query ;-)

Typically, your code would look a bit like this :

```
$query = "select ...";  // note : don't forget about escaping your data

$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
    trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$query); 
} else {
    // use the resultset
}
```

Comment: thank for answering i did what you said and now it says  "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIKE '%%' LIMIT ,' at line 1"

Comment: Well, it seems you have an error in your SQL query ;-) Looks like your don't have the `$_POST` data you expected ? Same for `$start` and `$member_number`, btw  ;; are you sure your form POSTs to this page ? Maybe it's using GET, in which case you'd have to look in `$_GET` instead of `$_POST` ?

Comment: actually the $mumber_number is 5 and i have a text field which is named search but the error appears when i first open the page in browser so i dont write anything in search box. If i write, nothing changes too. And  $start= ($page-1)*$member_number;  i use it with $_GET.

Comment: You shouldn't execute that query when no data has been submitted, then.

Comment: Comments never being executed. You have to code desired behavior, not comment it.

Comment: That's what I do in my own code, obviously *(except I'd use PDO, and exceptions)*...

Comment: @pascal how shouldnt i execute that when no data has been submitted?