# Warning: pg_query() [function.pg-query]: Query failed: ERROR: unterminated quoted string at or near

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a query where I get the error:

The code is:

```
$prefix = $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$row][2];
$fiyat = $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$row][3];
$increment = $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$row][4];
$tarih = $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$row][5];
$tarih = explode('.',$tarih);
$effective_date = $tarih[2] . "-" . $tarih[1] . "-" . $tarih[0];
```

All variables returns correct values (and variable types).

```
$query_insert_to_rates = "INSERT INTO rates VALUES (nextval('routes_seq'), '$prefix', '$i_tariff', '$fiyat_orj', '$fiyat_orj', '$increment', '$increment', '$forbidden', 't', '0', '0', '$increment', '$increment', NULL, '$eff_date_ins', NULL);";
```

$result_insert_to_rates = pg_query($query_insert_to_rates);

```
INSERT INTO rates VALUES (nextval('routes_seq'), '21321', '8', '0.0470', '0.0470', '1', '1', 't', 't', '0', '0', '1', '1', NULL, '2012-06-01 00:00:00.000001+02', NULL);
```

> Warning: pg_query() [function.pg-query]: Query failed: ERROR: unterminated quoted string at or near "'2" at character 50 in.....

Now, when I run the query within the PHP, I get the above error. My PHP Version is 5.3.10. And the machine is Centos 5 (VPS).

However if I run the query through Navicat(connected to the DB) then I have no error, and query executed perfectly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For safety's sake, please use parametrized SQL queries. http://bobby-tables.com/php.html has example code. It should also take care of your problem because the PDO interface library will take care of formatting the SQL in a way that Postgresql wants it. For that matter, you should be using PHP's PDO database abstraction layer, rather than the `pg_query` family of functions. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Please also post the output of `echo $query_insert_to_rates;`.

Comment: INSERT INTO rates VALUES (nextval('routes_seq'), '21321', '8', '0.0470', '0.0470', '1', '1', 't', 't', '0', '0', '1', '1', NULL, '2012-06-01 00:00:00.000001+02', NULL);

Comment: Search in the server logs for the exact SQL text of the failing query.  Because according to the error message it is different from what you send.

Answer (score 2):

This is terrible code: unsafe and insecure. Don't use this pattern ever

```
$SQL = "INSERT ... ('$var1', '$var2')
```

use PDO parametrized queries or pg_escape_string function instead

[pg_escape_string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266090/whats-does-pg-escape-string-exactly-do)

Comment: It will work as a local and not open to internet. And also only one person will use it. When i use pg_escape_string: the original number is '7717' and when i use pg_escape_string it becomes '7\0007\0001\0007' which is not making sense.

Comment: you newer know, where and who will be use your application - and who read this thread - I tested pg_escape_string and it works well - probably you have wrong internal PHP type: <?php $x=6666; echo pg_escape_string($x); ?>