# Variables inside PostgreSQL/PostGIS query in PHP file

Tags: php, postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to use variables inside PostgreSQL/PostGIS query in PHP file.

Variables need to put lat and lng values inside POINT geometry, but something does not work well inside my code and I receive error message:

> Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: parse error - invalid
>   geometry HINT: "POINT(" <-- parse error at position 6 within geometry

When I run query that have values (instead of variables) for the POINT

`SELECT ST_AsText (the_geom) as location, name, intptlat, intptlon FROM tiger_match WHERE ST_INTERSECTS (the_geom, ST_Buffer((ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-85.1043 34.315)',4326)), 0.1));`

everything works fine.

I read some articles and post on the net but I can not find solution:

- http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/how-do-i/how-do-i-use-php-with-postgresql/#.
- [Whats does pg_escape_string exactly do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266090/whats-does-pg-escape-string-exactly-do)

Entire code that I use in php file is below:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "postgres"; 
$pass = "2907"; 
$db = "postgis";

$intptlon = pg_escape_string($_GET['intptlon']);
$intptlat = pg_escape_string($_GET['intptlat']);

function parseToXML($htmlStr) 
{ 
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr);
return $xmlStr; 
} 

// Opens a connection to a PostgreSQL
$con = pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$db user=$user password=$pass") or die ("Could not connect to server\n"); 

$query = "select ST_AsText (the_geom) as location, name, intptlat, intptlon FROM tiger_match WHERE ST_INTERSECTS (the_geom, ST_Buffer((ST_GeomFromText('POINT('$intptlon' '$intptlat')',4326)), 0.1))";
$rs = pg_query($con, $query) or die("Cannot execute query: $query\n");

header("Content-type: text/xml");
// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';

// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @pg_fetch_assoc($rs)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
  echo 'intptlat="' . $row['intptlat'] . '" ';
  echo 'intptlon="' . $row['intptlon'] . '" ';
  echo 'the_geom="' . $row['location'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
}
echo '</markers>';
?>
```

Comment: Try changing `POINT('$intptlon' '$intptlat')` to `POINT($intptlon $intptlat)` or better - use parameters for query.

Comment: See the manual on parametrised queries: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php

Comment: I try to use parameters for query, and change my query to `$rs = pg_query_params($con,"select ST_AsText (the_geom) as location, name, intptlat, intptlon FROM tiger_match WHERE ST_INTERSECTS (the_geom, ST_Buffer((ST_GeomFromText('POINT($intptlon $intptlat)',4326)), 0.1))");` , but I now receive a error `pg_query_params() expects parameter 1 to be string` . Is this part of the code also need to be changed `$intptlon = pg_escape_string($_GET['intptlon']);` so I can use parameters for query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Don't mix parameters for WKT with SQL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24486/how-to-insert-a-point-into-postgis/24487#24487). Either create the WKT (*T* for **text**) using conventional string utilities, then feed that string parameter to the query, or use an alternative geometry constructor that takes numeric parameters, such as `ST_MakePoint(x, y)`.

The query should look something like this:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(the_geom) as location, name, intptlat, intptlon
FROM tiger_match
WHERE ST_DWithin(the_geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($intptlon, $intptlat), 4326), 0.1);
```

In general, don't buffer geometries to do proximity searches. In this case it was one point, but some folks also do this to whole tables, which is unnecessarily expensive. Also, your distance is 0.1 degree, which is a non-sense distance unit. If you use a `geography` type, then it will use metric distances.

Comment: Thanks Mike T, this works, I change my query to `$query = "SELECT ST_AsText(the_geom) as location, name, statefp, intptlat, intptlon FROM tiger_match WHERE ST_DWithin (the_geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint('$intptlon', '$intptlat'), 4326), 0.01)";` and also I change `$intptlon = pg_escape_string($_GET['intptlon']);
$intptlat = pg_escape_string($_GET['intptlat']);` to `$intptlat = $_GET["intptlat"]; $intptlon = $_GET["intptlon"];` and everything works fine :)