# "Call to a member function fetch_row() on a non-object" in spite of error handling

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to execute a query but php/mysql throws

> Call to a member function fetch_row() on a non-object

even though

```
if(!$results)
```

should filter out empty results. The error message points to

```
$row = $results->fetch_row();
```

This is the whole code:

```
<?php
$query = 'DELETE FROM `products` WHERE `company` ='.$id_nummer;

$results = $link->query($query);
if(!$results)
{
  echo $link->error;
}
else
{
  $row = $results->fetch_row();
  $wanted_result = $row[0];
}
?>
```

Where is the cause for this?

EDIT: I solved it by replacing

```
if(!$results)
```

with

```
if(!is_object($results))
```

and it works.

Comment: Did you initialize your variable `$link`?

Comment: Why do you expect results returned from a `DELETE`?

Comment: I don't believe this should have been closed as localized.  I have been trying for hours to get my code working from the php docs and from examples online.  The suggestion to use is_object fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to fetch a row from a a query as an object, however the query that you are making is a DELETE which doesn't return values that can be fetch as a row, but a boolean (TRUE or FALSE) that is the result of the query being successful or not.
In this case, $result should return the value TRUE or FALSE, that can be used like this for example:

```
<?php
$query = 'DELETE FROM `products` WHERE `company` ='.$id_nummer;    
$results = $link->query($query);

if(!$results) {
    echo $link->error;
} else {
    echo "Company id:".$in_number." successfully deleted."
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fetch results from a `DELETE` query, as there are no rows to fetch.  The contents of `$results` is a boolean true or false, based on success or failure of the `DELETE`.

In your case, it is `TRUE`, and your `if (!$results)` evaluates to `FALSE`, sending you into the `else`.

`$results` itself will tell you whether or not the action succeeded (whether the query was syntactically valid), but `$link->affected_rows` will tell you if you actually managed to match and delete any rows.

```
if ($result && $link->affected_rows > 0) {
  // You managed to delete something
}
else if ($result) {
  // successful query, no rows deleted
}
else {
  // Error
  echo $link->error;
}
```

Since you appear to be using MySQLi, consider creating a prepared statement instead of `query()` for this.

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("DELETE FROM `products` WHERE `company` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id_nummer);
$stmt->execute();

// Then check affected rows
if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
  // Successful deletion of some rows...
}
```

Comment: What is the advantage of using a prepared statement over my approach?

Comment: @JackyRank The advantage is always security, as you don't require sanitization of the input (though you may still benefit from validation) see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732561/why-is-using-a-mysql-prepared-statement-more-secure-than-using-the-common-escape

Comment: Good. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323476/number-of-variables-doesnt-match-number-of-parameters-yes-they-do

Comment: @JackyRank I'm glad to see you're trying it out. The effort up front may seem large, but you get used to the few extra lines of code and it really pays off in security.  (and the first answer there is correct -  you ought not quote the placeholders `?` not `'?'`.

Comment: That leads to "Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object"