# Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters - Yes they do

Tags: php, mysqli

So according to a suggestion I am trying to include prepared statements.

But PHP doesn't accept my code.

```
$stmt = $link->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE `company` = CONVERT( _utf8 \'?\' USING latin1 )  COLLATE latin1_german1_ci AND `password` = CONVERT( _utf8 \'?\' USING latin1 ) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci');
$stmt->bind_Param('ss',  $firmaP, $kennwP);
$firmaP = utf8_encode($_POST['company']);
$kennwP = utf8_encode($_POST['password']);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
  if($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
      echo "OK";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "NO";
    }
}
```

I get

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match
>   number of parameters in prepared statement

Whereas I have two questionmarks in the query and two variables in bind_Param.

How to solve this?

EDIT: Replacing \'?\' with ? leads to

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Comment: You don't quote string arguments in your query when using bind parameters; you leave the bind statement to do that for you

Comment: you don't quote parameters. the db engine does that.

Comment: Does `$firmaP` and `$kennwP` have a value when you bind it to the statement?

Comment: I tried both, same result.

Comment: As I wrote, that doesn't work.

Comment: there is a possibility that convert doesnt support prepared statements at all. There is also a strict possibility that convert is also not needed here

Comment: That's it. I removed it and it worked.

Answer (score 7):

Don't quote your `?`s as follows:

```
$stmt = $link->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE `company` = CONVERT( _utf8 ? USING latin1 )  COLLATE latin1_german1_ci AND `password` = CONVERT( _utf8 ? USING latin1 ) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci');
$firmaP = utf8_encode($_POST['company']);
$kennwP = utf8_encode($_POST['password']);
$stmt->bind_Param('ss',  $firmaP, $kennwP);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
  if($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
      echo "OK";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "NO";
    }
}
```

Comment: Results in Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Comment: +1. The whole point of parameterised queries is that you don't have to quote the fields.

Comment: @SDC I was told it was security.

Comment: @JackyRank Check `$link->error` after attempting to call `prepare()`. This may be an odd case where the syntax of `CONVERT()` causes problems

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski It is the Question mark: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? USING latin1 ) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci AND..."

Comment: @JackyRank So the `?` placeholder apparently doesn't work inside `CONVERT()` when you are packing it with a charset.  Normally, there would be no space between the charset and the expression, like `_utf8'thestring'`. Does it work if you omit the space (which you had originally)?