# Is there any way to bind parameters to this prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
"UPDATE rooms SET Donators=CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Donators, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(Donators)-1),' ', '\"?\" : \"?\",}') WHERE Id=?"
```

I want to bind 3 variables to this query string, but the problem is that, it the first two ? aren't treated as markers. Is there any way to get them treated as markers? At the moment I am getting a warning:

> mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in C:\xampp\htdocs\main.php on line 62.

Comment: You need to make the string in PHP and bind it as a whole.

Comment: If you quote the marker it isn't a marker any more, it's a string.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález is there any way around it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters - Yes they do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323476/number-of-variables-doesnt-match-number-of-parameters-yes-they-do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not quote the variable anchors.

Combine the variable you are trying to inject into its own anchor:

```
$var1 = 'something';
$var2 = 'something2';
$variableToInject = "$var1 : $var2";
```

Inject that variable in its own anchor:

```
"UPDATE rooms SET Donators=CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Donators, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(Donators)-1),' ',?) WHERE Id=?"
```