# Why wont this mysql update script work?

Tags: php, mysql

I have been beating my head against a wall for a few hours now trying to get this to update my DB.

```
<?
//edit_item_data.php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","Inventory");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  $sql= "UPDATE Item 
          SET Catagory = '$_POST[Catagory]',
          Cost = '$_POST[Cost]',
          Condition = '$_POST[Condition]',
          PurchaseLot_PurchaseLotID = '$_POST[PurchaseLot]',
          Location = '$_POST[Location]',
          Desc = '$_POST[Desc]',
          Notes = '$_POST[Notes]'
          WHERE 
          ItemID = '$_POST[id]'";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
 settimeout('self.close()',5000);
</script>
```

this is the error I'm getting

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Condition = New,     
PurchaseLot_PurchaseLotID = 1, Location = e' at line 4
```

I'm running mysql 5.6 and php 5.5. I'm sure its something dumb but I can't for the life of me see what it is.

Comment: Your SQL statement is invalid because you have several string variables placed unquoted directly into it, which is invalid.  What you have is highly [vulnerable to tampering via SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection). It is a good time to take a step back and read the [MySQLi documentation on prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to alleviate both your quoting problem and the large security problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real issue was lack of grave accents

```
        SET `Catagory` = '$_POST[Catagory]',
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you are hilariously vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) doing what you are doing, but the problem is that you aren't enclosing your variables in quotes, e.g:

```
SET Catagory = '$_POST[Catagory]',
-- etc
```

Use [mysqli_real_escape_string to escape your variables](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) before you put them into your SQL, like this:

```
SET Catagory = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['Catagory'], $con) . "',
```

Comment: I have try this but it still is gives me the same error message

Comment: this will be made more secure once i understand prepared staments a little better. But this will also exist in a vpn environment only. It will never see the open web.

Comment: Fair enough - you've put quotes around all of your variables?

Comment: I've updated the code above to reflect the changes I made. Its still giving me the same error.

Comment: Dear Lord.(Pardon if that offends) It was back ticks..`````

Answer (score 0):

[image: xkcd]

You want something like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `Item` SET
   `Catagory` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['Catagory'],$con)."',
   `Cost` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['Cost'],$con)."',
   ........
   WHERE `ItemID` = ".intval($_POST['id']);
```

Side-note, it's spelled "category".

---

EDIT: If you, like me, can't be arsed to type out such a long function name...

```
$e = function($str) use ($con) {
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($str,$con);
};
```

Then:

```
... `Catagory` = '".$e($_POST['Catagory'])."' ...
```

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated, -1 for suggesting - **edit** nice quick edit there, I'll take it back

Comment: Psh, so I missed the "i". Sue me.

Comment: and the connection resource

Comment: Also, prepared statements are more robust than `*_real_escape_string`

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Unless you need variable column names.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO *shrugs* I still use `mysql_query`, so I can't really argue. The vulnerabilities come from improper use, not an innate problem.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Have fun with that. I'll leave you with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732561/why-is-using-a-mysql-prepared-statement-more-secure-than-using-the-common-escape).