# Do I need mysqli_string_escape statement to avoid sql injection

Tags: php

Do I need mysqli_escape_string to avoid sql injection if I use mysqli prepared statement

Comment: FYI, escaping does **not** prevent injection.

Comment: No, if you use bind variables, you don't use mysql_escape_string, otherwise everything will be double-escaped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't, prepared statements will ensure that your queries are sanitized properly.

In fact, prepared statements are the **safest** way to prevent injections, escaping is never 100% safe.

This explains why: [Why is using a mysql prepared statement more secure than using the common escape functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732561/why-is-using-a-mysql-prepared-statement-more-secure-than-using-the-common-escape)

---

- Consult the following links regarding [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: thank you for the link, ill go through the article. All you people have been great in answering and guiding me. Thanks again